# How to find the Pubkey of the user who made a transaction using Solana web3.js websocket

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, solana-cli, solana-program-library

I have tried the following WS methods to get live updates for certain Solana account:

- [connection.onLogs()](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#onLogs)
- [connection.onAccountChange()](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#onAccountChange)

But none of them displays the Publickey of the wallet that is performing/signing the transaction. Is there a way to obtain this information via websockets?